# Not submitting reviewed manuscript

Tags: paper-submission

I have just addressed reviewers’ comments to one of my papers. I am the first author and did most of the job.

One of the authors does not want to resubmit. They offered no explanation and have been avoiding me. How to behave in this case?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own question. Please see [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) for an explanation, and some possible alternatives.

Comment: Did your co-author tell you why he/she does not want to submit? They may have a good reason and it may be worth for you to listen to it carefully and take it into account.

Comment: The problem in the question changed a lot due to some edits. Right now it sounds as if one of the co-authors doesn't want to give his/her approval for submission, which is a completely different problem than the initial problem where co-autor said to submit, but apparently didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Ask both the editor and the colleague to change the corresponding author to yourself. Make it one mail to both parties. Explain in the mail that there has been a mixup and you want to correct it. You don't need details in a first correspondence, but supply them if required.

Hopefully the journal's procedures will permit this and hopefully your coauthor won't cause a stink.

Comment: In fields of research where corresponding author has a lot of prestige, this would be very dangerous advice.

Answer (score 1):

To complement Buffy's good answer, here's a potentially more diplomatic option: You could email the editor the revised manuscript, indicating that your coauthor had resubmitted it previously but apparently something had gone wrong on the way.

You could even inform your coauthor about that action beforehand, without necessarily having to wait for their response/approval.

This might be slighly less confrontative then asking to transfer the corresponding author, in which case the editor might check with your coauthor, causing a potentially awkward situation.

Comment: @neutroshock Now resubmitting as a single author does not sound like a smart idea. Basically it means that either this or the previous submission was unethical.

Comment: @neutroshock No, it is not, but this does not justify you submitting the same paper on your own.  Unless, of course, the other author did not contribute enough to be a coauthor, in which case they shouldn't have been a coauthor on the first submission to start with.  Unethical behavior is not made ethical by other unethical behavior.

Comment: @neutroshock Anyway, it seems you had recurring bad experiences with them - so you should stop publishing with them, and potentially tell your peers.

Comment: @neutroshock I think this is more tricky than you would like it to be.  But it feels that the ethics of this would be another question.  (Might have seen some similar questions here.)

Comment: @neutroshock As I said, which action is ethical etc. is a matter for another question.

Comment: No need for a rant here.  But consider that you submit it with you as a sole author and the new referee happens to know that this used to be a work with two authors: From a preprint you posted (did you?), from a conference talk, or it might even be the same referee as for the original submission.  What would you say if the referee wrote the editor that the very same paper used to have two authors, and one apparently was just taken off the paper?

Comment: Well, the reviewer from the previous submission of the manuscript could complain as well, if he/she is to review it again.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the very same paper, which you submitted with two authors and for which you apparently got referee reports (since you are talking about a revised version)?  Imagine the other journal sends it to the very same referee.

Comment: Being upfront about it to the editor is certainly the safest (and ultimately best) way: The editor might disagree, but for sure you don't risk being accused of any kind of dishonesty.  I think this is clearly the best option! (And then I also wouldn't see any ethical issues.)